# How to remove the trailing dot after TLD by using mod_rewrite?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

There are some website, such as:

```
http://example.org
```

After the top- level domain I want to prohibit to put the dot:

```
http://example.org.
```

My .htaccess (relevant part):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)\./?$ /$1 [L,R=301]

...

</IfModule>
```

This works for such requests, for example:

```
http://example.org/news./ -> http://example.org/news/
http://example.org/solutions./ -> http://example.org/solutions/
```

But if I put the dot just after the first-level domain, this dot remains:

```
http://example.org./ -> http://example.org.
http://example.org. -> http://example.org.
```

I would be very grateful for the information. Thanks to all.

Comment: I never knew such an address was possible; you learn something every day :)

Comment: The "trailing dot" has cropped up a few times on [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/), such as [How can URLs have a dot at the end?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/73934/1243) and [How should websites handle hostname with trailing dot?](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/73989/1243)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert this rule just below `RewriteBase` line to remove trailing dot in domain name:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+?)\.$
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302,NE]
```

This has been a discovery for me that a trailing DOT is allowed by web servers in domain name. Even `https://www.google.com./` and `https://www.google.com/` work similarly.